# In regards to taking notes, highlighting, etc. - Is it permissible to write inside the Torah, Siddur and other holy books?

Tags: torah-study, prayer-book, shulchan-aruch, torah-writing

I am studying for Jewish conversion and have many books that I am using. I write inside my commentaries and Jewish guidance books, but I am unsure as to whether or not I can do the same inside my Torah, Siddur and Shulhan Aruch. Please advise?